# Convert Serially Read Data to HEX form

Tags: c#

I am reading data from Serial port on click of a button by using Methods

```
byte[] query = new byte[8] { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xC4, 0x0B };

serialPort1.Write(query, 0, query.Length);
incoming = serialPort1.ReadLine();
Textbox1.text=incoming;
```

I am storing the serially read data in variable Incoming i want this data to be converted in HEX form for further processing

Comment: byte[] asBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(incoming);

Comment: ReadLine returns a string. Do you just want the char values as HEX? Like in a Hex-Editor?

Comment: Yes i am reading String and i want all characters in string to be  in HEX

Answer (score 1):

here is an example for Hex conversion

```
byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(incoming);
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qMugTS)

Comment: Can you please assist me what first line is doing

Comment: why you are converting the string to bytes, why you are not converting directly? @simonare

Comment: I tried your instructions but my GUI is hanged now its doin nothing

Comment: you are doing something wrong I guess. Check my working Fiddle

Comment: BitConverter.ToString is returning me data as 01-03-04-0A-D5-15-A9-26-FD which is correct, the only data of my concerned is 0A & D5 respectively these elemets  basically are temperatures value in HEX form, how can i access those so i can do further calculations?

Comment: `var splittedResult = result.Split('-');` `splittedResult[3]` and `splittedResult[4]`  is what you need

Comment: Exeption IndexOutofRange is popping out when i write splittedresult[3] as per your instructions

Comment: mate this means that length of your string is not enough for the split operation. A0-D5 is stored in 3rd and 4th position in your example string

Comment: what do you mean length of my string is not enough for split operation

Comment: when you split `01-03-04-0A-D5-15-A9-26-FD`, you got string array with 9 strings in it. if you cannot use my code in this string, it means that your input string is smaller so 3rd and 4th element is not available

Comment: your method is only woking for Index0 returning 01 as result for other indexes from 1-8 i am getting same exception

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wt50tI my code is in Module section, i dont have experience how to use fiddle so thats why i copied my all code in Module section

Comment: just make it console application and share that one. your code need to include sample data. And it must be working :)

Comment: in Console its working properly, any other by which i can share my whole work with you